# How can I transfer a file using scp without a password from a Perl script?

Tags: perl, passwords, scp

I am writing a Perl script that needs to transfer files between computers using scp. I know about public key authentication, but I need the script to be fully automated, so I can't visit the machines to set up the keys before the script is run.

Is there any way to either pass the password to scp from the Perl script or set up the keys from within the perl script?

This script will be run as part of a build script that also reimages the hard drive I need to run the script on. So I can't be there to set up keys every time the project is built.

Comment: So you can't set up an authorized_keys file on the machines in advance but you can set up the same password for every machine? No matter how you do it, this is a bad idea. Keys are the only correct answer for what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can automate the setting up of authorized keys. Although that would probably mean you have to hard code the password in script that does that.

Comment: Why not make the authorized_keys part of the original image?

Comment: The build will be done on different hardware, and the hard drive of the machine I'm transferring the file to won't be reimaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Perl [Expect](http://p3rl.org/Expect) module, see [an example at Well House consultants' forum](http://www.wellho.net/forum/Perl-Programming/User-creation-and-password-setting-in-Perl-code.html).

Its documentation has a [telnet example](http://p3rl.org/Expect#How_to_automate_login) which is easily changed for SSH.

[Net::SSH::Expect](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aExpect) is another Perl module to do exactly what you want. I haven't used this one previously, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/Net-SSH-Perl-1.34/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm). Below is the sample code you can use.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Net::SSH::Perl
my $cmd = 'command';
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("hostname", debug=>0);
$ssh->login("username","password");
my ($stdout,$stderr,$exit) = $ssh->cmd("$cmd");
print $stdout;
```

This code will simply run the given 'command' on remote machine and give you the output on your local system. So, to instead of scp, you can use this script with command 'cat' to capture the output of 'cat filename' on local system and redirect the output in file on local system.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of ssh-agent. And if you use Gnome, Gnome Keyring SSH Agent is wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

Just create keys that don't have passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [SSH-Key](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password) (without a password).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
######################################################
#                                                    #
#                                #
#       Script to send files to server    #
#               Author: Jurison Murati               #
#                                   #
######################################################

use strict;
use Net::SCP::Expect;
use File::Copy;
use IO::Compress::Gzip qw(gzip $GzipError);
my $host = "192.168.0.1";
my $user = "user";
my $pwd = "password";
my $RemoteDir = </nodes>;
my $file;
my $displaydate= `date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`;
print "Filloi dergimi date $displaydate\n";
my $scp = Net::SCP::Expect->new(host=>$host,user=>$user,password=>$pwd,recursive=>1);
my $dir = '/arch';
        opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;
while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
        $scp->scp("$dir/$file","$RemoteDir") or die $scp->{errstr};
print "file $dir/$file moved on date $displaydate\n";
}
exit 0;
```

Comment: Its always good to Write a short description of what you have done so its easier to understand your code.